# Distance and Acceleration Pseudocode

Tags: distance, physics, pseudocode

I need help with this Distance and Acceleration pseudocode. The question is in the photo below.

I have completed my structure chart, and I have two of my three modules done. I cant figure out how to take my distance formula, with my seconds input and get to my calculation module.

[image]

Comment: Ok, what kind of help do you need?

Comment: ah yes, a do-my-homework-that-i-haven't-even-tried question.

Comment: I really loved this guy's innocence. _Here. Solve the third one._ <3

Comment: I have completed my structure chart, and I have two of my three modules done. I cant figure out how to take my distance formula, with my seconds input and get to my calculation module.

Comment: I haven't fully figured this website out. This isn't a I haven't done my homework question I have tried to but I cant figure out the best way to state it  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the program code in C. I hope you'll write pseudo code from this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define G 9.8

double distance(double sec)
{
    return (0.5*G*sec*sec);
}

void printDistance(double sec)
{
    int i;
    double d, tot_d = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < sec; i++)
    {
        d = distance(i+1);
        d -= tot_d;
        printf("Distance in %dth second : %lf\n", i+1, d);
        tot_d += d;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double sec;
    printf("\nEnter the time in seconds : ");
    scanf("%lf", &sec);
    printDistance(sec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that code, I'm not sure how to put that into pseudo code, but I will attempt it.

Comment: I have done almost everything. You should do it yourself. Good Luck Bro!!

Comment: Thank you so much!